# UIPageControlとUIScrollViewの連携

Tags: swift, xcode

Xcode6 + SwiftにてStoryboardで設置したUIPageControlとUIScrollViewを連携させたいのですが、

```js
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    //UIScrollViewの紐付け
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    //UIPageControlの紐付け
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

紐付けしか出来ず、肝心の中身ついては何も書けず……
スライドと共にLabelとImageを表示させたいのですが
お詳しい方がいましたら、UIPageControlとUIScrollViewの連携の仕方を教えてくださると幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

`UIScrollView`と`UIPageControl`を連携させるためにはスクロール位置(`contentOffset`)と選択ページ(`currentPage`)を互いに同期させる必要があるため、両者のイベントを処理する必要があります。

`UIScrollView`についてはViewControllerに`UIScrollViewDelegate`の`scrollViewDidScroll`を実装します。

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollview: UIScrollView) {
    pageControl.currentPage = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width
}
```

`UIPageControl`はtapを拾います。

```
@IBAction func pageControlTapped(sender:AnyObject) {
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * pageControl.currentPage, 0)
}
```

Comment: Storyboardで既に高さや幅の数値は設定しているのに、ViewControllerで再度設定する必要があるのでしょうか？

Comment: 少し追記しました。設定しているのはサイズではなく、ユーザーに操作されると変わる性質の値です。

Answer (score 0):

まず、サンプルコードを載せます。（コメントをいただいた後で、加筆しています。Page Controlをタップしたときの処理、スクロールビューをスクロールしたときの処理、両方に対応しました。）

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func changePage(sender: UIPageControl) {
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: scrollView.bounds.size.width * CGFloat(sender.currentPage), y: 0.0), animated: true)
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        var page = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.bounds.size.width)
        pageControl.currentPage = page
    }

}
```

Page Controlは、ボタンなどと同じUIControlサブクラスです。Outletとしてでなく、Actionで「接続」します。そのとき、senderの型を、AnyObjectからUIPageControlに変えておくと、コードを書くのが楽になります（senderを型変換せずにすむ）。サンプルでは、UIPageControlのActionメソッドをchangePage()としています。
スクロールビューをスクロールするのに、メソッドscrollRectToVisible()を使っていましたが、やはりメソッドsetContentOffset()を使ったほうがコードが短くなるので、変更しました。
ここで注意すべきは、Swiftでは異なる型の四則演算ができないことです。CGFloat（浮動小数点数）とInt（整数）のかけ算はできませんので、一方（ここではIntのほう）をCGFloatに変換（CGFloat(value: Int)）しています。
Scroll ViewのDelegateメソッドは、scrollViewDidScroll()でなく、scrollViewDidEndDecelerating()を使います。前者を使ってみるとわかりますが、Page Controlをタップすると、点滅が起きます。これはユーザのアクションだけでなく、プログラムによるスクロールでも、Delegateが発生するためだと考えられますが、それを回避するためです。前者のメソッドは、スクロールのアニメーションの途中で動きますが、後者のメソッドは、アニメーションが完了した時点で動くという違いがあります。

Comment: ご回答有り難うございます。
試してみたのですが、ビルドすると落ちてしまいます…。
UIScrollViewDelegateなどのクラスを実装しなくても出来るものなのでしょうか？

Comment: Storyboard上の設定は、説明していません。していませんが、必須な設定はいくつかあります。

UIScrollViewDelegateは、逆にスクロールビューをスクロールしたときに、UIPageControllの表示を変更する処理に使います。それはサンプルコードでは触れていません。

Comment: なるほど……！今やっと理解しました。
教えて頂いたサンプルコードで引き続き、作業してみます。